# SuiteScript 2.0 attach email to multiple transactions

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0

I'm using the N/email module to send an email that I'd like to attach to multiple transactions. With a single transaction using the following code, I have no issues:

```
email.send({
    author: -5,
    recipients: recipient,
    subject: subject,
    body: body,
    relatedRecords: {
        transactionId: 8
    }
});
```

The documentation does imply, however, that we can associate multiple transactions when it says transactionId should be

> The Transaction record(s) associated with the Message record.

However, none of the following examples have worked. The email is sent without error for all of them, but it is not attached to either of the transactions. I'm at a bit of a loss.

```
// Example 1
email.send({
    author: -5,
    recipients: recipient,
    subject: subject,
    body: body,
    relatedRecords: { transactionId: [8,10] }
});

// Example 2
email.send({
    author: -5,
    recipients: recipient,
    subject: subject,
    body: body,
    relatedRecords: [{ transactionId: 8 }, { transactionId: 10 }]
});

// Example 3
email.send({
    author: -5,
    recipients: recipient,
    subject: subject,
    body: body,
    relatedRecords: { transactionId: '8,10' }
});
```

How is this supposed to be accomplished?

Comment: did you ever figure this out ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you have this worked out, but I believe it should look like this:

```
email.send({
    author: -5,
    recipients: recipient,
    subject: subject,
    body: body,
    relatedRecords: { transactionId:8,transactionId:10 }
});
```

> "relatedRecords:
>   Object that contains
>   key/value pairs to
>   associate the Message
>   record with related
>   records (including
>   custom records)."

Comment: Do you how to build the transactionId list dynamically? I cant create an object with duplicate key names, Is there a way in Suitescript?